# How can I transform this String?

Tags: shell

Good afternoon, I'm a bioinformatics student and I'm trying to put some strings between commas with a space. The output looks like this: `NC_037078.1:122545-124035,NC_037078.1:96630-98120` and I want it to be like this: `NC_037078.1:122545-124035, NC_037078.1:96630-98120`

The document is like this:
1. rrn16 
16S ribosomal RNA [Genlisea aurea]
Other Aliases: C7J69_pgr001, BK572_Gau_0120
Genomic context: Chloroplast
Annotation:  NC_037078.1 (122545..124035, complement)
ID:` 36166080

The script until now looks like this:

```
code=$(ls -l | grep "Annotation" data.txt | cut -d " " -f3,4 | sed 's/[(]/:/g' | sed 's/[)]/ /g' | sed 's/[,]/ /g' | sed 's/[ ]//g' | sed 's/["."]/ /g' | sed 's/ /./1' | sed 's/ /-/g' | sed 's/-//1' | tr "\n" ",")
```

Comment: My first thought is, wow, that's a lot of transformations all piped together. Nothing wrong with that if it works but a little hard to debug. I don't have time just now but I'd recommend trying to figure out either a somewhat more compact one or two sed replacement patterns or a more flexible scripting approach like that suggested by M__.

Comment: The `ls | grep` is pointless, it isn't doing anything useful here.

Comment: I can see where you get `NC_037078.1:122545-124035` from your example, but where does `NC_037078.1:96630-98120` come from?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a small change. Anyway try ...

```
perl -p -e 's/(.*NC_[0-9]+\.[0-9]),(NC_[0-9]+\.[0-9].*)/$1,\s$2/g' data.txt
```

If you have happy that this works, then repeat with an `-i` flag

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(.*NC_[0-9]+\.[0-9]),(NC_[0-9]+\.[0-9].*)/$1,\s$2/g' data.txt
```

I've not checked the code, but it's worth checking whether `.*` is really needed. Its a while since I've used Perl